# Twilio: Don't want to keep logs of voice callers' numbers

Tags: twilio, privacy

I use Twilio to operate an automated phone line that connects callers to resources for some very sensitive topics. If the phone numbers of callers were revealed due to a data breach or subpoena, it could have negative consequences for them. There's no need for us to log callers' numbers, and ideally I'd like to not store that information at all. However, these numbers show up in my usage logs:

[image: screenshot of twilio logs showing callers' numbers]

I've searched for ways to prevent these numbers from being logged or to delete them after they've been logged, but I can't find anything documented. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: You can delete the record of a call using the [API DELETE functionality](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#delete-a-call-resource):

`DELETE https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{Sid}.json`

You can have a script periodically [request all calls made to the number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#read-multiple-call-resources) and call DELETE for each one. If your system involves recordings, transcriptions, or texts, you need to do the same for them.

This is an acceptable solution for our needs, but it would be ideal if the numbers weren't logged in the first place, so I'm still interested in hearing others' answers.

Comment: There's also the question of any internal logging the company does for billing, abuse, fraud, troubleshooting, etc. This data is almost certainly not subject to any customer control. See: https://www.twilio.com/legal/